# Where to install ESLint in react + server project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git

I have a project folder with a react client and express API with the below folder structure where `my-project` is the git repo.

```
my-project
  -client
  -api
```

I'm confused on where to install ESLint and prettier so that the whole project has a husky pre-commit prettier format hook.

ESLint asks if the project runs in the browser so it seems I should install ESLint to both `client` and `api` separately since only `client` runs in the browser.

ESLint also asks what kind of modules the project uses, but `client` uses import/export and `api` uses `require/exports`.

Then it seems prettier should be at the project level for the pre commit hook which I have working, but not sure where to put ESLint.

Comment: you can nest eslint configurations. install the package at the project root with an eslint.config.js or whatever the filename is; then extend that with configurations within the client and api folders as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks @Derek 

So at the parent level it's irrelevant if I choose import/export or require/exports and browser vs node b/c at the nested level I will specify which one it should be?